# Extension of power series representation of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-continuation

While reading the spectral radius formula (Theorem 18.9) in *Real and Complex Analysis* by Rudin, I found myself unable to understand the following: Rudin first defined a holomorphic function $f(z)$ on a ring region $\{z\mid |z|>r\ge 0\}$, then he proved that, when restricted to a *smaller* ring region $\{z\mid |z|>R\ge r\}$, $f(z)$ can be represented as a power series $\sum a_n z^n$, whereupon he concluded that not only on the smaller region, but also on the original bigger region where $f(z)$ is holomorphic, it still has the same power representation; in other words, $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ is still valid on $\{z\mid |z|>r\}$.

From my limited knowledge in complex analysis, I just can't recall any such properties of power series (or Laurent series, more accurately put) as the one stated above. I have a vague impression of analytic continuation (which I never mastered), is it relevant here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges for some $z = z_0$ then $a_n z_0^n \to 0$ and so it converges for $|z| < |z_0|$ by comparison with the geometric series. The same reasoning applies to a Laurent series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$, if it converges for $z= z_1$ and $z= z_2$ then it converges on the annulus $|z| \in (|z_1|,|z_2|)$

Comment: @user1952009 oh thanks! Actually it's even simpler because, as I forgot to mention, $n$ sums from $0$ to infinity in that series. I think your comment suffices for a complete answer.